# Display locale language ("english" instead of "en") with I18n and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, translation, locale

I'd like to display "English" if the page is currently in English, "Français" if in French, ect. I have a locales/languages file for a bunch of languages set up, but I have no idea how to call them.

I realize I could create a special translation on each page, but I was wondering if I18n had a simple way to call this, like I18n.locale.langauge (which obviously I know doesn't work).

I'm hoping this is a rather simple thing to do, but if not I can go about with translations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there are no built in ways to do this.

Your logic seems right, simply add an entry to the .yml file i.e:

```
en:
  locale: English

fr:
  locale: Français
```

and use

```
t 'locale'
```

in your pages :)

Comment: Ok, thanks :) I didn't know if it was built in or not. I'll do that then, thanks!